# Microservices connection in a Java (and Docker) application

Tags: docker, connection, microservices

I have built my Maven app and dockerized it successfully. Although, in order for the final .jar & the container eventually to run as needed, the app needs to connect to some services (MongoDB, Apache Kafka, etc.).

So, I'm trying to find a way to pass those services as arguments that they can easily change without affecting any relevant part of the source code. For example, now my app should connect to a "testing" database and then to "production" one. Those two database instances are hosted at different endpoints. I need to find a way in order to not rerun the build pipeline only for just ammending the endpoint of a service.

Answer (score 0):

Store all that configuration (ip, ports, ...) inside environment variables. Group all that variables inside a file per environment.

When running your application in a stage environment, pass the container the stage env file. When running your application in real environment, pass the container the real env file.

By this approach you do not need to change your code between environments. Only configuration files.

You can read more about this approach in the following links.

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/
- https://cloud.google.com/architecture/twelve-factor-app-development-on-gcp#3_configuration